# How to include multiple \Sexpr values within LaTeX math mode tags?

Tags: r, latex

As part of my work, I am expected to show calculation steps with sample values.  To do this, I usually just replace the variable names with \Sexpr{} to add in the values.  For some reason \Sexpr{} escapes math mode and breaks some of my tags.  For instance, this works well:

```
$r_{pump} = \sqrt{(x_{pump} - x_{obs})^{2} + (y_{pump} - y_{obs})^{2}}$
```

It results in all values being correctly placed under the square root tag like this:

[image: [Correct Square Root tagging image here](http://i.imgur.com/PxtfZjw.png)]

However, when I try to include \Sexpr{} tags to incorporate values like this...

```
$\sqrt{(\Sexpr{x[1]}(m) - \Sexpr{x[2]}(m))^{2} + (\Sexpr{y[1]}(m) - \Sexpr{y[2]}(m))^{2}}$
```

...I get results that look like this:

[image]

This happens when I try to include \Sexpr{} in a \frac{}{} tag as well.

Am I applying math mode ($\Stuff$) incorrectly?

Comment: Can you post the corresponding line from the `.tex` file you generated? Maybe there is a clue there.